# Can't add iAd delegate to ViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iad

I'm trying to add iAd into my project. I'm following this tutorial http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/

I just added the iAd.framework package to my project and set it as Weak.
I added `#import <iAd/iAd.h>` into my .h file but whenever I try to add the ADBannerViewDelegate it doesn't show up in the intellisense, which means it's not accessible to me.

Same thing for ADBannerView class and the delegate methods (in case I add the delegate anyway).

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try building it? Some times the intellisense isn't updated immediately, but that doesn't mean it won't compile and build.

Comment: Yeah, I tried. Didn't give me any errors but also doesn't seem to work. Are there any other requirements to use iAd other than importing the framework?

Comment: Did you set it to "Device" instead of "Simulator"? Sometimes XCode gives wired results when you haven't chosen "Device".

Comment: Really weird. I did both - Restart Xcode and set it to Device. Still doesn't show me the options on intellisense but at least seems to work now. Thanks guys. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Just write it up as an answer so others can refer to it.

Comment: 2 days until I can accept my own answer. Someone better write that. :)

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart XCode and set your target to "Device". The framework might not show up on intellisense but should work nevertheless.

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator